# Java: Different byte[] has same string in utf8

Tags: java, string, utf-8, byte

There are two different byte array.When i get String from byte[].They have same value when i use utf8. Opposite when i use ISO-8859-1.

```
    byte[] valueFir = new byte[]{0, 1, -79};
    byte[] valueSec = new byte[]{0, 1, -80};

    Charset CHARSET = Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1");
    Charset UTF8SET = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
    Charset[] list = new Charset[]{CHARSET, UTF8SET};

    for(int i=0; i<list.length; i++){

        String fir = new String(valueFir,list[i]);
        String sec = new String(valueSec,list[i]);

        Assert.assertNotEquals(fir,sec);
    }
```

First assert is true,Second assert is fail.
what's the reason?

Answer (score 4):

If you look at the [Javadoc for the `String` constructor that you're using](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String-byte:A-java.nio.charset.Charset-), it says

> This method always replaces malformed-input and unmappable-character sequences with this charset's default replacement string.

Now in UTF8, the bytes -79 and -80 don't map to individual characters.  So both your byte arrays make no sense in UTF8.  And because they're unmappable, you're just getting the default `String` twice.  Your `assertNotEquals` is then comparing the default `String` to itself.

However, your byte arrays make perfect sense in ISO-8859-1, and get converted to two different `String` values.